# Why does GTA V open with 'Not Optimum mode. Recommended mode 1440x900 60Ghz'?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, monitor

When I opened GTA V, my monitor blacked out and a pop up showed saying:

> Not optimum mode. Recommended mode 1440 x 900 60Ghz

What to do? How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a problem with a monitor, not a game.

Comment: @Frank - I don't see how this is different to any of the other [game-to-monitor issues](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor) we've allowed here, and the solution is game-related (by setting GTAV's resolution to 1400x900, as DangerZone's answer seems to cover the problem fairly well :-) ).

Comment: @Robotnik I mostly see it as tech support.  *Any* application, game or otherwise, would make this happen, if it changed the resolution.  Ergo, it's not a gaming issue.

Comment: @Frank - Sure, any application could cause this behaviour, just as any application could also not register input from the keyboard/mouse, crash with an error or require driver updates to function properly, but that doesn't stop us asking/answering those questions where they relate to a game being played. With the context of this question being pretty firmly tied to GTA V, I'd say it's within our 'tech support' expertise. :-)

Comment: @Robotnik I would disagree with that.  How a monitor works isn't in our expertise at all.  Heck, when *Windows* makes the same thing happen, it's pretty safe to say this isn't a gaming issue.

Answer (score 3):

It's just suggesting a resolution setting for you. You don't really say whether it gives you the option to change it at that moment or what monitor you have etc., but you should be able change your resolution and run the game just fine.

Even if it's not the optimum resolution, it's possible that you can still play the game in a less-than-optimum setting, it just won't look "perfect".

Comment: Its probably suggesting the native resolution of the monitor, but the reason it is being displayed is that the selected resolution is not supported. The OP may have chosen something too high or too low, or the monitor just doen't like 16:9 aspect ratios (the suggested resoultion indicates a 16:10 monitor or tv)